# Extract substring from end till first alphabet in java

Tags: java, string, substr

I have a string of format: A-2-Q4567

More examples: AB-456-T12, A24-5-M12345, etc.

I want to extract the last numerical values out of these strings, which are: 4567, 12, 12345 respectively (which is the numerical value of the substring from the end till first non-numeric character is encountered)

I can split the string, get the last string from the splitted string array, and then do a parseInt after removing the non-numerical characters from it.

But is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `regex`: `(\d+$)`. It returns the last sequence of digits in the string.

**EDIT** - some explanation:
The `\d` means any digit.
The `+` means one or more of the previous symbols. Since the previous symbol is a digit, then `\d+` means "one or more digits".
The `$` means the end of the string, so `\d+$` is the **last** sequence of digits in the string.

Comment: Nice answer, but a bit more explaining would be nice (e.g. what is the control character `\d`, the `+` and the `$`)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
String getLastNumeric(String input)
{
    String str="";
    char c;
    for(int i=input.length()-1;i>=0 && Character.isDigit(c=input.charAt(i));i--)
        str=c+str;
    return str;
}
```

The regex solutions might be more elegant but performance-wise I think the above is the best because Regex match can be more expensive than a simple for loop with a simple condition to evaluate.

Ofcourse The Regex is more flexible, what if your requirements change and now a dash "-" must precede the numbers ? with Regex it should be just a matter of changing one regex expression.

I put the Regex version here but remember if you're sure your requirements won't change I think the above solution is better on the CPU :

```
Matcher matcher= Pattern.compile("(\\d+$)").matcher(input);
if(matcher.find())
    return matcher.group();
return "";
```